# Pass data to included blade view

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Let's say that I have the following main view:

```
<div>
    <div>
        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <div>
        @include('sidebar')
    </div>

    <div>
        @include('footer')
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I make sure that the included views have their own data? For example, in the sidebar I want to display, let's say, new blog post comments. In the footer I want to display new users and blog posts. Maybe using `@include` is not the right way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your applications, app service providers boot method do something like

```
View::composer('sidebar',function($view){
$comments= Blog::latest()->comments;
  $view->with('comments',$comments);
})

View::composer('footer',function($view){
$users= User::latest();
  $view->with('users',$users);
})
```

//sidebar

Then in the view file do something like

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
 {{$comment->data}}
@endforeach`
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views) in such case.

Answer (score 0):

Write your logic in [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views) then call it using a service provider, in the boot method

```
View::composer(
    ['partials.content', 'partials.sidebar', 'partials.footer], 'App\Http\ViewComposers\MyViewComposer'

);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm tried this and it's working with me :

```
@include('content',array("key"=>"value"))
```